# Changing the shape of a Nurbs Path that's already animated

Tags: nurbs-surface

I don't think I asked my question to its fullest earlier.

I have a NurbsPath animation. The tube NurbsPath shape wraps around the cylinder.

Is there a way to alter the shape of this object (NurbsPath) to where it's not a tube shape, but instead a block shape? Without losing my rigged animation?

I have tried numerous options, some recommended on BSE, but nothing works. I could be doing it incorrectly.

A suggestion posted earlier was to do the following (that did not work):

1. Change the profile of the generated mesh by giving another Curve object as the Bevel object
2. Add a Bezier Circle and adjust the points to create the shape you want, then set the Bevel settings

The issue I see so far is that the NurbsPath has already been converted/created/and cannot be edited in its shape from anything I've tried.

UPDATE -- I figured it out, and it was quite easy - all I had to do was delete the Subdivision Surface Modifier.

[image]

[image: Nurbspath]

Comment: You seem to have deleted your previous question. It’s better to update the question to clarify, rather than remove the old question and any associated answers. While it might not be useful to you, it could be useful to someone else.

Comment: OK will do - still hoping someone can help

Comment: Now you’ve created this one, you can include a link to the previous one. It would be good if you can describe why the other solution didn’t fix the problem too.

Comment: It's the same link/file - I will edit the post to explain

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple and I just didn't see it -
Delete the Subdivision Surface Modifier.
[image: sub surface]